# Run React Native project with yarn without installing global packages?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg, npx

I usually run React Native projects with `npx react-native start` -> `npx react-native run-ios`. I'm collaborating on a project that uses yarn instead of npm. If I run `yarn` to install the project's packages, is there a way to then run the project using yarn instead of npx, and without having to install the global `react-native` package?

Answer (score 0):

If the project was setup using `npx react-native init ...`, you should have default commands in package.json to execute the app.

e.g. "ios": "react-native run-ios"

Therefore you could use `yarn ios (or) yarn android` to fire up the app.

P.S. Not entirely sure if you can run it without having the react-native cli installed globally on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Init the project with `npx react-native@latest init yourProjectName`

And use `yarn` instead of `npx` when running React Native commands inside your existing project.

[image: docs page]

e.g: Instead of `npx react-native start` use `yarn react-native start`

You can read more on RN [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)